# How to cover set<Employee__c> parameter in static method

Tags: apex, unit-test, set

how to cover Set of value parameter in test class. please check below my code

```
 public class test {

    public static Decimal testamount(set<Employee__c>Emp, string state){
     ----
     -----
    return null;
    }
```

Comment: For static methods, simply call `ClassName.MethodName(parameters)`, example- `test.testamount(new set<Employee__c>(), 'state');`. Always refer to documentation or trailhead ([module Get started with Apex unit tests](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro))

Comment: @Goldberg Never name class as 'Test', this might lead into problems for your test classes.